# segfault 0x8B at SDL_quit() after only making display window

Tags: segmentation-fault, sdl-2

I have some barebones code that is giving a segfault (0x8B) on one of my computers, but not another. Running Ubuntu on both (14.04.3 on problematic PC and 14.04.2 on my non-problematic laptop), developing in codeblocks on both.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include    <cstdlib>
#else
#include    <stdlib.h>
#endif


#include    <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include    <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
    {
    // initialize SDL video
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *screen = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game Window",
        0,
        0,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED);

SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

The code throws the segmentation fault at `SDL_Quit();` on my PC, but not my laptop. I believe it is something with the compiling process, because if I compile on my laptop and run on my PC, the PC throws no errors. If I compile on my PC, I get a segfault on both my PC and laptop. I have checked that I am indeed compiling with identical options on both machines, and the problem persists.

Not sure where to go from here? Thoughts?

EDIT:
Despite suggestion by JPD in comments, problem remains. The problem is for sure to do with the screen, however, because removing the call to `SDL_CreateWindow()` prevents a segfault at `SDL_Quit()`

EDIT2:
Still learning about debugging, segfaults are new to me, and just now ran the program via gdb from command line and have some new info now, still not sure what to do with it

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x606b00) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66
66  ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
```

I can't find this file on my PC setup, but also I don't have this file on my laptop either. So not sure why one computer is complaining while the other isn't. ideas?

EDIT3:
found this https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8735&sid=fd6401057fbfe9cfdd04a5445a3dbbab but don't understand the implementation of a workaround yet, if this is what is relevant to my problem too.

EDIT4:
as per the link in EDIT3, I have tried adding `-pthread` in both the compiling and the linking commands, but still no solution. I have tried these flags both preceding and following the references to SDL2 libraries.

EDIT5:
static linking to SDL2 and SDL2_gfx libraries fixed problem, but not sure why dynamic linking fails. backtrace follows:

```
#0  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x606b00) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66
#1  0x00007ffff600c2c7 in XrmDestroyDatabase () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff5ff47b3 in _XFreeDisplayStructure () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff5fe24ef in XCloseDisplay () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b81360 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff7b7395e in SDL_VideoQuit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff7b4df75 in SDL_QuitSubSystem () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff7b4e01e in SDL_Quit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#8  0x00000000004019f3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdee8) at main.cpp:371
```

Comment: Try using `SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);` before `SDL_Quit();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, JPD. Unfortunately, I get the same outcome. No problem running `SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);` but it doens't help the segfault at `SDL_Quit();`

Comment: Do your two computers have two different versions of the library you are linking to?  And are you statically linking it, or dynamically (probable)?

Comment: linking dynamically. I installed both using `apt-get install libsdl2-*` and have even tried on my PC building my own libraries from source.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is not in pthread_mutex_lock.c, so seeing the source is not likely to help.  But if you could print the call stack that reached that line, it might be telling.

Comment: how do I get a call stack to post? Sorry, still a bit of a newb. In the mean time, adding `-Bstatic` to compiling and linking commands allows it to exit cleanly without a segfault... not sure why the dynamic linking is a problem, maybe this is a clue? I don't think I care how i link really, but I would like to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: adding `-Bstatic -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx -Bdynamic` works. In dynamic linking, I also had `sdl-config --libs` added to my options as well, and read that changing this to `sdl-config --static-libs` was suggested. However, this was interpreted to add `-lpthread` which seemed to still be a problem, as noted in the post I linked to in EDIT3. Looks like I don't have to link that or `-pthread` at all, and removing `sdl-config --static-libs` or `sdl-config --libs` altogether was the only way I could make this work via codeblocks compiling. Got to this via testing my own build commands in CLI

Comment: My gdb skills are a tad rusty.  `bt`, for back trace might get you that call stack.  I asked about linking only because I thought you might have inconsistent versions, and did not expect a change to solve the crash.  Since you do want to investigate, take a look at `https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/src/SDL.c`, if you don't already have the source.  It shows your quit call just breaks down into separate subsystem calls you could do.  You might want to try them separately, so see which triggers the crash.

Comment: see my EDIT5, #5 `SDL_VideoQuit()` seems to be the culprit, but I'm not sure how to interpret #4 `in ??`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87211/discussion-between-user1246135-and-donjuedo).

Comment: Static linking uses archive libraries `*.a` whereas dynamic linking links to shared objects `*.so`. You might have multiple versions of the same library in your system. Try to list the dependency of dynamically linked program by running `ld -r program`. I bet the compiled version on either PC or laptop will have different dependencies. Post the result as an EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has resolved after updating my video drivers.